# Is there a way to dynamically create a repeating object property structure in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a tree object that is basically just an array of following object repeating indefinitely.

```
treeNode = {
 label: 'Some label',
 children: treeNode
}
```

When A user clicks on a tree node I have a function that creates an array of indexes to the clicked node. Basically something like path = [0,3,4,5,1] and I use this to pop out the node at that location using the code below.

```
pop = tree[path[0]].children[path[1]].children[path[2]].children.pop();
```

This works because I currently know how many levels deep the click is in this function. However I would like to make this dynamic and in some sort of loop, but am unsure how to do it. For example I would like to have a function like this:

```
for(i=0; i<path.length -1; i++){
 branches += path[i].children;
}

return tree[branches].pop();
```

That obviously does not work, but I am hoping for something along those lines. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: `children` is an **array** of tree nodes, right? (You've used `pop`.) It's just it doesn't look like that from the first code block showing the structure.

Comment: Should your tree object not be `children: [treeNode, treeNode, ...]` ?

Comment: And should your example be using 0, 3, 4, 5, and 1 instead of 0, 1, and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the parent node, then use `splice` to remove the node at the final index in the path:

```
function popPath(tree, path) {
    // We need at least one segment
    if (!path.length) {
        throw new Error("path must have at least one segment");
    }

    // Find the parent node
    let node = tree;
    for (let i = 0, len = path.length - 1; i < len; ++i) {
        node = node.children[path[i]];
    }

    // Remove and return the child (which is the first entry in the
    // array `splice` returns
    return node.children.splice(path[path.length - 1], 1)[0];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const tree = {
    label: "Top label",
    children: [
        {
            label: "0 label",
            children: [
                {
                    label: "0 0 label",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    label: "0 1 label",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    label: "0 2 label",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    label: "0 3 label",
                    children: [
                        {
                            label: "0 3 0 label",
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            label: "0 3 1 label",
                            children: [
                                {
                                    label: "0 3 1 0 label",
                                    children: []
                                },
                                {
                                    label: "0 3 1 1 label",
                                    children: []
                                },
                                {
                                    label: "0 3 1 2 label",
                                    children: []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function popPath(tree, path) {
    // We need at least one segment
    if (!path.length) {
        throw new Error("path must have at least one segment");
    }

    // Find the parent node
    let node = tree;
    for (let i = 0, len = path.length - 1; i < len; ++i) {
        node = node.children[path[i]];
    }
    
    // Remove and return the child (which is the first entry in the
    // array `splice` returns
    return node.children.splice(path[path.length - 1], 1)[0];
}

const node = popPath(tree, [0, 3, 1, 1]);
console.log("removed node:", node);
console.log("updated tree:", tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

Comment: I am trying to remove the node at that location from the children array

Comment: @user10012 - `splice` is the tool for popping at a specific index. I've updated the answer to show how to use it.

Comment: I had the change the line in the for loop to "node = node[path[i]].children;" and the return line to "node.splice(path[path.length - 1], 1);" but now it works perfectly. I didn't know you could do that. Does this work because node is just becoming a reference to the location in the original tree?

Comment: @user10012 - Odd, your structure must be slightly different to the one in the snippet. Yes, the `node` variable is updated to refer to each node in the tree as we traverse it.